# Setting NSUserDefaults Directly In Custom Getter / Setter

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, nsuserdefaults

So I have a small value that needs to by synced across my app through NSUserDefaults.  I found myself saving and getting the value from NSUserDefaults a bit and I thought it might be nice to link a Getter / Setter directly to NSUserDefaults.

Here's my Getter / Setter code:

```
- (void) setSomeProperty:(id)someValue {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:someValue forKey:@"someProperty"];
}

- (id) someProperty {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"someProperty"];
}
```

Here's How I Access:

```
someClass.someProperty = @"SomeValue"; // -- Set's To @"SomeValue"

id someValue = someClass.someProperty; // -- Assigns Value From NSUserDefaults
```

This way, when I update or retrieve the property, it is always directly accessing the NSUserDefault Value.  To me it seems like a simpler way to write to and retrieve values from my NSUserDefaults, but perhaps there is something problematic or a performance consideration with this that I'm overlooking.  Feedback / Concerns are appreciated.

#### Question

Is this acceptable practice, and will this cause problems later on?

Comment: I do the same thing. I've never seen a problem.

Comment: i think it's absolutely ok to do that except that you should call synchronize when saving value to defaults

Comment: @AndreyChernukha You do not need to call `synchronize` every time you set a value. Defaults are automatically synchronized on occasion by the OS.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, I can now proceed with a certain peace of mind!

Comment: @rmaddy If you want to guarantee that the value is always saved, you want to call `synchronize`. It might not always get saved if you're killing the app using Xcode while debugging, or if the app crashes shortly after you make a change to the value, unless you call `synchronize`. I agree, though, that it's not required.

Comment: @Gavin Yes, you make valid points i didn't get into. I do a few things - 1) I call `synchronize` in the app delegate method when the app will enter the background. 2) I call synchronize after setting a value if it's really important value that must be set even if the app crashes a second later. When debugging, I always put press the Home button before killing the app in the debugger If I'm worried about defaults being fully synced.

Comment: I also call synchronize in my appDelegate willEnterBackground, in this case, the data isn't so crucial that if I lose the most recent update all is lost.

Comment: @rmaddy i know it is written in the documentation, but i swear it never works without calling synchronise

Comment: @AndreyChernuka -- Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep a closer eye on it!

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I have no problem under normal circumstances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is ok, but has some implications that you should be aware of.

NSUserDefaults is disk-based storage. As such is it significantly slower than memory-based solutions. On iOS, "disk-based" means flash memory, which is still significantly slower than memory-based storage.

Flash memory also has a limited number of write cycles before it fails.

For these 2 reasons, I would not use the above technique for values that change rapidly, or where you require fast response.

Also, I'm assuming that since you say "...synced across my app..." you mean shared between multiple objects.

I would suggest making sure to document these properties in your header so it's clear that they are shared, persistent properties. Adding the words "shared" or "saved" to those property names would be a help, in addition to descriptive text in the header.

If your only requirement is shared access, and you don't need persistence, you might look at using a data container singleton instead of using user defaults. (You create a singleton object that has properties that you want to share, and then you fetch a pointer to the singleton from anywhere in your app and use it to read/write the properties that you want to share.)

You could even use a hybrid approach, where you collect these properties in a singleton, and implement persistence in the singleton. This has the advantage of centralizing your save/read logic in one place, so you can change it to use a different storage method if you decide to at some future date.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, it's already set up as a singleton for session resources, just using this for a couple values that need to be saved on app closings!  Is the cache system also flash, or is it just the synchronize process?

Comment: All persistent storage in iOS is flash memory. That's what the "Hard drive" in iOS uses.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find it much better to just get the defaults in the procedure that you wish to use. So:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString* myValue = [defaults stringForKey:@"mykey"];
//manipulate myValue;
```

... You can clearly see your intent in the code.

Comment: The abstraction of calling `someClass.someProperty` can make the code look cleaner and be easier to read. Plus it reduces the number of places where you could accidentally type `@"myKey"` instead of `@"mykey"`, and makes maintenance simpler too.

Comment: I guess, that makes sense. I usually have the keys in a constant file though.

Answer (score 1):

No technical reason not to do it. Some will tell you that a property may signal to other developers that it's a simple getter/setter, and not something that invokes reads from the hard drive or a remote server.

It can depend on the context - perhaps if you name your class in a way that communicates that it's some sort of an object that is tied to storage it will be better. You won't have performance issues unless you use the properties excessively (inside of inner loops, retrieving it multiple times in the calculations instead of using a variable, etc). Otherwise I'd use 2 methods instead with a "load"/"read" and "save"/"write" prefixes to their names so that other developers know they should cache the values and only call them when they need data that is up to date.

Edit: For 99% of the cases, though, you'll be fine doing just what you described. Personally that's what I do, but I think you should be aware of the concerns I described in the answer.

Comment: A precedent for using properties to set something that is not a simple getter/setter but instead is tied to storage: Core Data model objects. I think it's perfectly acceptable to do this with `NSUserDefaults` as well, because the overhead is pretty minimal. It's only if you start storing massive amounts in `NSUserDefaults`, or maybe setting stuff many times in loops that you could have issues, but most of the time you shouldn't have to worry at all.

Comment: @Gavin I agree, edited my comment. Also, doesn't CoreData cache the changes to NSManagedObjects and then commit them when you call some specific function? I don't think the properties are actually tied to the storage and modify it when you set a new value to your properties.. But its been a while since I used CoreData...